CDF of geometric distribution
In Blitzstein & Hwang, there's a problem about getting the CDF of the geometric distribution (support = {1,2,3,...}). I'm trying to use the same approach to get the CDF of the shifted geometric distribution (support = {0,1,2,...}), but I'm tripping over my intuition.
First, the original problem:

A coin is tossed repeatedly until it lands Heads for the first time.
Let X be the number of tosses that are required (including the toss
that landed Heads), and let p be the probability of Heads, so that X ∼
FS(p). Find the CDF of X, and for p = 1/2 sketch its graph.

This can be elegantly solved using the geometric series formula. But it can also be solved using the complement of the CDF like so:
$$
X \sim Geometric(1/2)
$$
$$
P(X = k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p
$$
$$
P(X \leq k) = 1 - P(X \gt k)
$$
Here, $P(X \gt k)$ means "X is greater than n, where all $X_{n}$ events are failures", ie. $(X \gt n) = (X_{1}=0, X_{2}=0, ..., X_{n}=0)$ (These are meant to be sets, but for some reason I can't escape curly braces). This equals $(1-p)^n$, so the CDF equals $1 - (1 - p)^n$.
Now, following the same procedure, I want to obtain the CDF of the shifted geometric distribution:
$$
X - 1 \sim Geometric(1/2)
$$
$$
P(X = k) = (1-p)^kp
$$
$$
P(X \leq k) = 1 - P(X \gt k)
$$
Here, I'm confused what set of events $P(X \gt k)$ signifies. Other Internet sources suggest to change the complement to $P(X \leq k) = 1 - P(X \ge k+1)$ and thus obtain the CDF as $P(X \leq k) = (1-p)^{n+1}p$, but that confuses me even more because I can't wrap my head around what $P(X \ge k+1)$ signifies, and why would I use that instead of $P(X \gt k)$?
If, in the previous case, $P(X \gt k)$ signified the set of failed trials before the first success, then in the shifted geometric distribution, where X counts the failed trials, does $P(X \gt k)$ signify the set of failed trials before the first success, minus one?

I think you are confusing yourself by using the same letter $X$ to mean two different things. Try it this way:
Let $Y = X - 1$, where $X \sim \text{Geometric}(0.5)$. $X$ is the original geometric distribution, and $Y$ is the shifted geometric distribution. Then
$$
F_Y(k) = P(Y \leq k) = P(X - 1 \leq k) = P(X \leq k+1) = F_X(k+1)
$$
You already found $F_X(n) = 1 - (1 - p)^n$, so plugging in $n = k+1$, you get
$$
F_Y(k) = F_X(k+1) = 1 - (1 - p)^{k+1}
$$
To your confusion--$P(X > k) = P(X \geq k+1)$ specifically because the support is non-negative integers. So $k+1$ is the first number in the support greater than $k$. In general, for discrete distributions, if $z$ is the first number in the support greater than $k$, then $P(X > k) = P(X \geq z)$.
